# Nginx proxy to ingress nginx controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Is it possible to use nginx proxy_pass without defining any location block?

Just send all incoming requests to nginx proxy to ingress controller.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) the only possible way to define `proxy_pass` directive is `location` context:

`Context: location, if in location, limit_except`